# How to get StyleCop Visual Studio extension to use rules from settings file?

Tags: visual-studio, stylecop

Our build system runs Style Cop somehow against rules in a file `Settings.StyleCop`.

My files break many rules. Since most of the transgressions are trivial, I'd like my computer to help fix them. I installed the StyleCop Visual Studio extension from http://stylecop.codeplex.com/ . Then I right-clicked on my project in Visual Studio and ran 'run StyleCop'.

This came up with a whole DIFFERENT set of trangressions to the build system. How can I get the Style Cop Visual Studio extension to run with the rules in the file `Settings.StyleCop`?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you either have a different version of StyleCop installed (so its triggering on new errors), or you have a parent settings file that is different to that on the build server. The easiest way I found to stop this was to stop merging in StyleCop settings from the solution root settings file (this can be configured via the StyleCop settings dialog in the IDE). Note that if you do this, you should also copy all the relevant settings from the parent settings file (usually found in the StyleCop installation folder).

The specific setting you're looking for is

```
<StringProperty Name="MergeSettingsFiles">NoMerge</StringProperty>
```